# 2 spaces to 1 space after punctuation and super/subscript

Tags: vba, ms-word, special-characters

I'm trying to write a macro in Word that will make 2 spaces into 1 space after a punctuation and formatting section, like this, where the 23-29 will be links to references at the end of the document.

dultricies.<sup>23-29</sup>  Purus

I would like the macro to identify the two spaces after the superscript and make it 1 space.

Thanks,

Chris

I tried creating the macro to identify 2 spaces and make it 1 space - that worked. But when I tried to create a macro using wildcard characters or special formatting (superscript), I expected Word to locate the the instance and make it one space, but it did not.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/49877-word-macro-super-sub-script-2-spaces.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a macro for this. All you need is a simple *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = ([ ^s]){2,}
Replace = \1
```